# Simple Register Form in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm Trying To Write a login/register system, i got the login down but i need help with registration

> Could not enter data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

My Written code

```
<?php
$dbhost = '';
$dbuser = '';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = 'INSERT INTO members '.
       '(id,username,password) '.
       'VALUES ( 2, test, test';

mysql_select_db('');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Registered\n";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Also i need a checker to see if the username is taken and assign a id, going up from whats in my DB, my db is a table called members, inside the table is ID(Ascending number(currently at 1)) Username, password.

I don't need the password encrypted, I have something in place for that elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This :

```
    // first check if username exist or not 
$rows = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='" . $_POST['username'] . "'";
$chk = mysql_query($rows);
if (mysql_num_rows($chk) >= 1) {
$userexist = "* This User already exist"; 
die();
// Then if not exist add it to DB 
} else {
$sql = "INSERT INTO members (id,username,password) VALUES ( 2, '" . $_POST['username'] . "', '" . $_POST['password'] . "')";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
}
```

Comment: It Only Wrote id 2 into my table?

Comment: In your database you should set your id 'AUTO_INCREMENT' then eliminate your id from INSERT INTO .

Answer (score 1):

You have two errors in your query:

1. You're missing quotes around your string values
2. You're missing the closing parenthesis around your values to be inserted

Try this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO members (id,username,password) VALUES ( 2, 'test', 'test')";
```

FYI, this is *much* easier to read on one line. I would avoid concatenation in your query if you can help it.

[Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).